# Should I ignore or totally block non-SMTP command attempts?

Tags: postfix, mail-transport-agent

I have a couple of messages appearing in my Postfix mail logs every day, like:

```
postfix/smtpd[7363]: warning: non-SMTP command from unknown[xx.xx.xx.xx]: GET / HTTP/1.0
```

Should I ignore them or block? If it is necessary block these attempts what is the best way to do this (iptables, postfix access maps, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use fail2ban.
You can edit /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/postfix.conf to catch any further attempts. I monitor my /var/log/mail.log files to look for suspicious behaviour and add to postfix.conf as required. Here is my postfix.conf which does catch the line you mention above.

```
[INCLUDES]


before = common.conf

[Definition]

_daemon = postfix/smtpd

failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)sNOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from \S+\[<HOST>\]: 554 5\.7\.1 .*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sNOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from \S+\[<HOST>\]: 450 4\.7\.1 : Helo       command rejected: Host not found; from=<> to=<> proto=ESMTP helo= *$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sNOQUEUE: reject: VRFY from \S+\[<HOST>\]: 550 5\.1\.1 .*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sNOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from \S+\[<HOST>\]: 454 4\.7\.1 :*$
        reject: RCPT from (.*)\[<HOST>\]: 550 5.1.1
        reject: RCPT from (.*)\[<HOST>\]: 450 4.7.1
        reject: RCPT from (.*)\[<HOST>\]: 554 5.7.1
    reject: RCPT from unknown\[<HOST>\]: 454 4.7.1
    connect from unknown\[<HOST>\]

ignoreregex =
```

you could also add

```
warning: non-SMTP command from unknown\[<HOST>\]:: GET / HTTP/1.0
```

if the above does not catch all.

If you wish to ban historical IP addresses manually then use IP tables.

Regards and good luck,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to block "the command". If you find that someone is doing a ton of invalid commands block that IP address. A invalid command won't hurt anything, and is in some cases practical (i.e. supporting buggy clients).

Comment: Ok, what is the best way to block these clients by IP?

Comment: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables instructions my vary by disto but this is the general idea. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/iptables-rules-examples/

Comment: What about using fail2ban?